# How can I fix shift-select-mode with own syntax-table

Tags: syntax-table, selection, shift-selection

So I have modified syntax table for moving with `C-<left>`.

```
 (defvar my-wacky-syntax-table
      (let ((table (make-syntax-table)))
        (modify-syntax-entry ?\( "w" table)
        (modify-syntax-entry ?\) "w" table)
        table))

(defun Pfedj/my-backward-word()
  (interactive)
  (with-syntax-table my-wacky-syntax-table
          (backward-char)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-<left>") 'Pfedj/my-backward-word)
```

It works fine for moving, but `S-C-<left>` for selecting with `control` does not work now. How can I fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say that this command is a navigation command, by replacing your

```
(interactive)
```

with

```
(interactive "^")
```

`C-h o interactive RET` explains that:

> [...]
>   If the string begins with `^` and `shift-select-mode` is non-nil,
>   Emacs first calls the function `handle-shift-selection`.
>   [...]